# Stack overflow using A* to solve 8-puzzle

Tags: python, stack-overflow, a-star, sliding-tile-puzzle

The goal for this code is to solve an N-puzzle (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle)

The function is meant to take in a scrambled list of integers 0 through (N**2-1), and return the list of moves to reach the solved state, where a move is a list of the x and y coordinate (e.g. [2, 2] means moving the bottom right piece in a 3x3 puzzle). I know only certain boards are solvable, and the board I am testing my code with is definitely solvable.

I tried implementing an A* search, but there seems to be something wrong with it, as for many boards I'm getting stack overflow. The board I use in the code below results in stack overflow, but this board will return the correct sequence of moves, after about 20 seconds (which seems way too long):
[7, 2, 8, 1, 5, 6, 0, 3, 4]

The basic idea is to start with a list of paths of moves, and then find the lowest cost path that has not been expanded (cost = current length of path + remaining manhattan distance), and expand that path, and keep going until the solution is found.

I understand that for an 8-puzzle bruteforcing might be just as if not more viable than A*, but I'd like it if my code could function for a 15-puzzle as well.

From my debugging, it seems like the code is kind of working as expected, I'm just not sure why it's taking so long and for most boards resulting in stack overflow. If I had to guess, I'd say that maybe I could eliminate more paths to speed things up, but I'm not sure how to do that without possibly eliminating the best path

I'm really new to programming, so is there a simple bug in my code, or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the algorithm? I am fairly confident my helper functions are working as intended, and that the issue is in the solve function. Any advice would be appreciated

```
import math
import copy

#Making move on board
def makeMove(board, move):
    L = int(math.sqrt(len(board)))
    copyBoard = copy.copy(board)
    zI = copyBoard.index(L**2-1)
    #Calculating move index in 1D list based off of x/y coords
    moveI = move[0] + L*move[1]
    copyBoard[zI], copyBoard[moveI] = copyBoard[moveI], copyBoard[zI]
    return copyBoard

#Function to find the board based off of the given path
def makeMoves(board, path):
    newBoard = copy.deepcopy(board)
    for move in path:
        newBoard = makeMove(newBoard, move)
    return newBoard

def mDist(board): #Calculating manhattan distance of board
    totalDist = 0
    L = int(math.sqrt(len(board)))
    for i in range(int(L**2)):
        #Finding sum of differences between x and y coordinates
        cX, cY = i % L, i // L
        fX, fY = board[i] % L, board[i] // L
        dX, dY = abs(cX-fX), abs(cY - fY)
        totalDist += (dX+dY)
    return totalDist

def nDisp(board):
    score = 0
    for i in range(len(board)):
        if i != board[i]:
            score += 1
    return score

def getLegalMoves(board):
    finalMoves = []
    L = int(math.sqrt(len(board)))
    #Finding the coordinates of the blank
    zI = board.index(L**2-1)
    zX, zY = zI % L, zI // L
    #Finding possible moves from that blank
    testMoves = [[zX+1, zY], [zX-1, zY], [zX, zY+1], [zX, zY-1]]
    for move in testMoves:
        if isLegalMove(move, L):
            finalMoves.append(move)
    return finalMoves

def isLegalMove(move, L):
    #Move is legal if on board
    for i in move:
        if i < 0 or i >= L:
            return False
    return True

def solve(board):
    queue = [] #List of paths, where a path is a sequence of moves
    for move in getLegalMoves(board): #Getting initial paths
        queue.append([move])
    def search(queue, board):
        bestScore = math.inf
        bestPath = None
        for path in queue:
            #Score based off of A* = estimated distance to finish + current distance
            dist = mDist(makeMoves(board, path))
            score = dist + len(path)
            #Checking if solved
            if dist == 0:
                return path
            #Finding best path that has not already been expanded
            if score < bestScore:
                bestScore = score
                bestPath = path
        #Removing the path since it is going to be expanded
        queue.remove(bestPath)
        bestPathBoard = makeMoves(board, bestPath)
        #Expanding the path
        for move in getLegalMoves(bestPathBoard):
            newPath = bestPath + [move]
            queue.append(newPath)
        #Recursing
        return search(queue, board)
    return search(queue, board)

print(solve([8, 0, 1, 6, 7, 3, 2, 5, 4]))
```

Comment: I don't see a priority queue anywhere. A* is based around a priority queue.

Comment: Why is your `search` recursive? Python doesn't optimize tail recursion; using tail recursion as iteration is asking for stack overflow.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for the reply. I'm not sure I totally understand the idea of the priority queue. I tried to implement it in my solve function. My idea was that the queue initially contains the initial possible paths, then it prioritizes which path is best by finding the one with the lowest score, on which it then expands. Is this idea wrong? Also, how else could I go about using the search function? Would a while loop really be any faster? Thanks

Comment: @Anon every time you call a function in a recursive call it adds a level to the call stack, if that stack gets too large you get a stack overflow, even if using a loop is slower ( which it may it may not be) at least you wouldn't get a call stack overflow error

Comment: @NickA thanks for that, but I feel like that is a bit of a workaround and is not really the heart of the problem here. Most implementations of solutions to this puzzle that I have seen solve the puzzle after checking far fewer paths than the stack limit. I would rather try to find out why it is hitting the stack limit rather than work around it, just to keep the code time efficient. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Well, you're using paths instead of board states for your search space. That's going to cause problems too. Also, your heuristic frequently overestimates the remaining distance. Really, there are a lot of problems here.

Comment: @user2357112 why is it problematic to use paths instead of boards? I wrote a function that can convert the initial board and a path into a new board. Plus, the path is the final product I want from the function. Also, how would the heuristic overestimate remaining distance? Isn't it proven that Manhattan distance is an admissible heuristic in N-puzzles? I am not saying you are wrong, this is simply what I understood from some other reading. Would you care to explain a bit more? Thanks

Comment: @user2357112 oh jeez, just noticed that I was including the blank in the calculation of manhattan distance, so much for the confidence in my helper functions. thanks for the advice

Comment: Equivalent boards may result from inequivalent paths. You have no mechanism to prevent such duplication, which is probably part of why you're recursing far enough to hit the stack limit. As for the heuristic, the problem I was thinking of is the one you just spotted.

Comment: @user2357112 good point, I just implemented something to account for that, and saw a significant improvement in efficiency. Even so, with a basic A* some 8-puzzles still end up checking over 1000 nodes. I read somewhere that using an iterative-deepening A* search will result in even faster speeds, and viability for solving the 15-puzzle. However, I don't really understand the approach of the algorithm in context of this problem. Could you explain it by any chance? Thanks again for all your help

Comment: That's way beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @user2357112 fair enough, if I can't figure it out maybe I'll just post a new question, thanks